# VBA, Use previous Column when it is stored as variable

Tags: excel, vba

I store my column in a variable.
NameColumn is equal to Column AD.

How do I store a new variable to NameColumn - 1? I want to store AC.

full code:

```
Sub FindAfterShort()

    Dim nameColumn As String   ' Name Column Letter
    Dim ScoreColumn As String  ' Score Column Letter
    Sheets("Load check data").Activate
    With Rows(1)
        nameColumn = Split(.Find(Sheets("Input").Range("A2"), .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, _
                xlWhole).Address, "$")(1)
        'PreviousColumn = NameColumn.Offset(0, -1)
    End With

    Debug.Print "Column Letters '" & nameColumn & "' and '" & PreviousColumn & "'."
    
    Dim k As Long
    k = Sheets("Load check data").Range("A1", Sheets("Load check data").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Debug.Print (k)
    
    Sheets("Load check data").Range(nameColumn & "2:" & nameColumn & k).ClearContents
    Sheets("Load check data").Range(.Cells(2, nameColumn - 1), .Cells(k, nameColumn - 1)).Copy
end sub
```

I have trouble on this line:

```
`Sheets("Load check data").Range(.Cells(2, nameColumn - 1), .Cells(k, nameColumn - 1)).Copy`
```

Unqualified references on `Cells`

Comment: The excelguy keeps forgetting the Excel tag haha.

Comment: YOU REMEMBERED!!!!!

Comment: Use the column number as your variable, instead of the column letter. Working with letters is clunky.

Comment: And use ```.Cells()``` in the range because it isn't going to like a numerical column in your current format.

Comment: It's not clear _how_ you use `NameColumn` to refer to a range, but however you do that, use `RangeReferedToByNameColumn.Offset( 0,-1)`

Comment: an important question here is what type of variable is `NameColumn`. While above comments are good, there are several ways to approach what you are after.

Comment: NameColumn is a string. I use a find based on a cell input. `NameColumn = Split(.Find(Sheets("Input").Range("A2"), .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, _
                xlWhole).Address, "$")(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing too much original code, this should work well.

```
With Sheets("Load check data")

    Dim nameColumn as Long
    nameColumn = .Rows(1).Find(Sheets("Input").Range("A2"), .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole).Column

    .Range(.Cells(2,nameColumn- 1),.cells(k, nameColumn - 1)).Copy

End With
```

Comment: Hey Scott im getting Object required on this, Im going to upload my full code to the question.

Comment: @excelguy - my edit should solve that issue. see how i work explicitly with each object. Your unqualified objects can hurt you (ie. - `With Rows(1)` and the like).

Comment: Getting object required on `nameColumn`

Comment: @BigBen - thanks for cleaning up my mess on this post. I clearly lost QC this time around!

Comment: Hi Scott, im getting `overflow` error on `nameColumn` line.

Comment: @excelguy - check that you are using `Long` variable type and not `Integer`

Comment: Hey scott, im using this `Dim nameColumn As Long`.  Seems Long!

Comment: i am at a loss. what's the column when you get that error? @excelguy

Answer (score 2):

When you say PreviousColumn, and if you are starting with AD, do you mean AC (you have written AE)?

If that's just a typo, how about something like this:

Add these function:

```
Private Function GetColNo(str_ColLetter As String) As Long

GetColNo = Range(str_ColLetter & 1).Column

End Function

Private Function GetColLetter(lng_ColNo As Long) As String

GetColLetter = Split(Cells(1, lng_ColNo).Address, "$")(1)

End Function
```

Then use them like this:

```
Dim NameColumn As String

Dim PreviousColumn As String

NameColumn = "AD"

PreviousColumn = GetColLetter(GetColNo(NameColumn) - 1)

Debug.Print (PreviousColumn)
```

This returns PreviousColumn = AC (since it's the column prior to AD)